# Output for C++ program is always -0

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write a program that converts Fahrenheit into Celsius by function and running it through a for loop with i = 0, i <= 20, i++

I've made a function that converts Fahrenheit and celsius and put that in a for loop that goes through 0-20 with i being the argument for the function but the output of the loop is always -0

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cmath>
   using namespace std;
   double celsius(double f){
     return (5/9)*(f - 32);
   }
   int main() {
     cout << "Celsius Temperature Table\n\n";
     for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
       double c = celsius(i);
       cout << i << "f is " << c << "c\n";
     }
     return 0;
   }
```

Comment: The result of `std::cout << (5/9) << std::endl;` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: `(5/9)` is always zero because of integer division because the compiler goes left to right it doesn't change it to a double until f is used.  So `return (f - 32)*5/9;` would return what you wanted.

Comment: thank you! I changed it and it now functions the way I intended.